# django admin doesn't display value

Tags: python, django

How to display the `Author` name correctly?
[image]

It only display a 'dash' there.

---

The following is my code.

### admin.py

```
@admin.register(Solution)
class SolutionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_original_question(self, obj):
        se = obj.question_code
        return format_html(se.question)

    def get_name(self, obj):
        se = obj.user_id.name
        return se

    fieldsets = [
        ('question', {'fields': ['get_original_question']}),
        ('author', {'fields': ['get_name']}),
        ('solution', {'fields': ['body']}),

    ]
    readonly_fields = ('get_original_question','get_name')
    get_original_question.short_description = 'question'
    get_name.short_description = 'author'
```

### Models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    question_code = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)

class Solution(models.Model):
    question_code = models.OneToOneField(Question, to_field='question_code', db_column='question_code')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('Users',to_field='id' ,db_column='ID')
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)


class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

### In django shell:

```
>>> Solution.objects.get(pk=1490).user_id
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aaron/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 178, in __get__
    rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
AttributeError: 'Solution' object has no attribute '_user_id_cache'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/aaron/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 184, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)
  File "/home/aaron/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 159, in get_object
    return qs.get(self.field.get_reverse_related_filter(instance))
  File "/home/aaron/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 379, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
den.models.DoesNotExist: Users matching query does not exist.
```

UPDATE: 
The following is my solution table[image]

UPDATE: add 1490 table[image]

UPDATE:

```
>>> Solution.objects.get(pk=180).user_id
<Users: John>
>>> Solution.objects.get(pk=180).user_id.name
'John'
>>> Solution.objects.get(pk=1490).user_id.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aaron/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 178, in __get__
    rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
AttributeError: 'Solution' object has no attribute '_user_id_cache'
```

UPDATE: user297
[image]

Comment: do you have the object in the database with user id? check the solution table. and remove the name from readonly field

Comment: Shouldn't it be `se = obj.user_id.name`?

Comment: @Exprator I cannot remove 'get_name' from readonly field, for it will cause `Unknown field(s) (get_name) specified for Solution. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class SolutionAdmin.`

Comment: @KlausD. I think so, but the result is still the same.

Comment: @Aaron do you have 1490 id in the table?

Comment: and do you have any __Str__ function to return the name to the admin panel in the model. or else this create a problem of returning objects and not field

Comment: @Exprator I add the picture for 1490 table.

Comment: Also your database column for `user_id` does not fit the one set in the `ForeignKey` (`ID`). Don't play with relations and their fields if it is no needed.

Comment: add a str function and return the name in your model of Users

Comment: I just want to give my 2 cents regarding naming conventions. Rename the `Solution` property `user_id` to `user`. You have an object as property, not just the id. Rename the class name `Users` to `User`. Model class names are singular. Variable names (class, method, property) should be as accurate as possible.

Comment: so your 1490 id is having the problem @Aaron, check your users model to find if that id was properly saved or not or might have been deleted

Comment: @KlausD.  @cezar  These models are from `inspectdb`, so it was from a existing database, that I want to use with other applications.

Comment: @Exprator I add a Picture. solutino id 1490 with User 297 exist. I found that user 1490 doesn't exist. This may cause the problem.

Comment: @KlausD. I  solve my problem according to your suggestion. 
Change the db_column to `user_id`
`user_id = models.ForeignKey('Users',to_field='id' ,db_column='user_id')`

Comment: @Aaron: great, the parameter `db_column` gives you the possibility to choose different property name in the Django model class than the db column name.

Comment: `to_field='id'` and `db_column='user_id'` are the defaults, so you can just remove the arguments.

Comment: @KlausD. If I remove `db_column='user_id'`,  it will show `(1054, "Unknown column 'solution.user_id_id' in 'field list'")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the solution model

```
class Solution(models.Model):
    question_code = models.OneToOneField(Question, to_field='question_code', db_column='question_code')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('Users',to_field='id' ,db_column='ID')
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The `user_id` field, I point to the wrong column, so change the db_column to `user_id`

```
user_id = models.ForeignKey('Users',to_field='id' ,db_column='user_id')
```

solve the problem.